# Is it possible to use a PositiveIntegerField as a foreign key in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, model, foreign-keys

Consider the following two Django models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    '''
    Represents a single item.
    '''
    title = models.TextField()

class Information(models.Model):
    '''
    Stores information about an item.
    '''
    approved           = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    multipurpose_field = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Due to the way the models are organized, I am forced to use a `PositiveIntegerField` in `Information` for referencing an `Item` instead of using a `ForeignKey`. This makes queries more difficult.

I would like to select all items referenced by an `Information` instance with `approved` set to `True`. In other words, I would like to do this:

```
Information.objects.filter(approved=True)
```

...except that the query will return instances of `Information` instead of the `Item` referenced in `multipurpose_field`.

I probably could do this with raw SQL:

```
SELECT app_item.title FROM app_item
  LEFT JOIN app_information
  ON app_information.multipurpose_field = app_item.id
  WHERE app_information.approved = 1
```

Is there a way to do this without resorting to raw SQL (which often isn't very portable)?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the reasons you are "forced to use a `PositiveIntegerField` in `Information` for referencing an `Item` instead of using a `ForeignKey`"?  That's what's making this hard.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Because it references rows from a number of different models depending on the context.

Comment: Ah - I don't think the ORM exposes any way to do that join directly, then.  I personally would use the generic relations available from the contenttypes framework to represent that, but those don't work in filters either.  You could probably do it with `extra`, awkward as that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ForeignKey`'s field type is determined by the related field. Consider redesigning your models this way:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id    = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.TextField()

class Information(models.Model):
    approved           = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    multipurpose_field = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

Then your query will be represented this way:

```
Item.objects.filter(information__approved=True)
```